# Return message in Jira out of Java (is only visible after page refresh...)

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I have problems with returning a message in Jira out of Java.

I made a plugin, overwriting the **CreateWorklog** class (the **doExecute()** method) when creating an issue.
After my functionalities the method ends with those lines:

```
[...]
if (NONE.equals(superResult))
{           
    return returnMsgToUser(getReturnUrl(), messageToUser, MessageType.SUCCESS, true, null);
}
return superResult;
```

And before that, there are some options to return before creating the issue, those look like this for example:

```
[...]
if (httpPostReq.getResponseCode() != 201)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: Webservice-Aufruf fehlgeschlagen! Response-Code: " + httpPostReq.getResponseCode());
    return returnMsgToUser(getReturnUrl(), "ERROR: Webservice call failed! Response-Code: " + httpPostReq.getResponseCode(), MessageType.ERROR, true, null);
}
[...]
```

The return argument makes the method cancels the issue-creation, but the return message is not as wanted.
First, the normal return message of the unchanged function appears, but after reloading the website, my own message appears.

Why it's only visible after refreshing the Jira website? How could I change that behavior?

***And another question:***
What exactly is the **String target** (last constructor parameter) doing in **returnMsgToUser**? The only information I could find, is that if you put in null, it's placed in a global spot. And what else could you put in there? I have no ideas...